# Which font has the following features?

Tags: fonts

I want to use a font available in TeX that have the following features:

1. Sans
2. **g** is as usual sans g
3. **a** likes uprighted italic math `$a$` ɑ
4. with ā á ǎ à and the like for o, e, i, u, ü, AOEIUÜ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html

Avantgarde suffie. Add `\usepackage{avant}` to use it.

Comment: It seems fine, albeit a little fat.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a sans serif font for your main text *and* for math, try the mathastext package. http://jf.burnol.free.fr/showcase.html shows many examples of the usage.

Answer (score 1):

You must be looking for a Pinyin font, right?

- The Monaco font on the Mac has all the features you want.
- If you cannot obtain Monaco, SimHei will also do, except that you’ll need to use U+0251 and U+0261 for upright script *a* and *g*, respectively.
- If you don’t stick with criteria 2) and 3), Arial Unicode MS would be another alternative.